# Issue in rails3 due to rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

Suddenly my is rvm is not working and showing me this error for all rails and rake commands.

```
  /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-                                                                                                 p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/gems/railties-3.2.8/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /home/hb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@demo/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

reinstall 1.9.3. Helps in many cases. rvm is somewhat of a hack so there can be many causes and trying a reinstall is the least painful.

Comment: I have tried with re-installing the 1.9.3 but no use,it was still same as before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have solved the issue.I just installed 1.8.7 and then I have installed 1.9.3.I think May be that was the dependency issue.

Comment: I was going to suggest you check `rvm requirements` but couldn't really see how that connected.